# Batch file when executing from another folder

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to execute a batch file (run.bat) to execute another batch file (clear.bat) located in another folder.

Run.bat looks like this:
`call "C:\Documents\BatchFiles\clear.bat"`

The clear.bat executes an exe that clears a portion of a .bin file. This batch works when executed independently.
`C:\Documents\BatchFiles\clearUtility.exe C:\Documents\BatchFiles\firmware.bin`

But when I execute the run.bat batch file the firmware.bin file does not get cleared.

Please help me with this.

I thank you in advance!

I tried adding a few more lines to the clear.bat file to see some output on console.
`C:\Documents\BatchFiles\clearUtility.exe C:\Documents\BatchFiles\firmware.bin

echo DONE!
pause`

I can see the output on the screen when I execute run.bat, but the firmware.bin file still does not get cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the clearUtility expects the binfile to be in the current working directory.
So change the clear.bat to first set the current directory before executing the clearutility.

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
clearUtility.exe
popd
```